After modifying the llvm-pass in AFL, it cannot work
I try to use AFL to do a fuzz test, but I find the llvm_mode/afl-llvm-pass.so.cc is written by an old version so I change it into this just to do a test.
#define AFL_LLVM_PASS

#include "../config.h"
#include "../debug.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "llvm/ADT/Statistic.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/Debug.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"

#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Passes/PassPlugin.h"
#include "llvm/Passes/PassBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/PassManager.h"


using namespace llvm;

class AFLCoverage : public PassInfoMixin<AFLCoverage> {
  public: AFLCoverage(){
  }
  PreservedAnalyses run(Module &M, 
                        ModuleAnalysisManager &MAM);
};

PreservedAnalyses AFLCoverage::run(llvm::Module &M,
                                   llvm::ModuleAnalysisManager &MAM) {
  
  printf("IIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOOOO");
  
  
  return llvm::PreservedAnalyses::all();

}

llvm::PassPluginLibraryInfo getInjectFuncCallPluginInfo() {
  return {LLVM_PLUGIN_API_VERSION, "AFLCoverage", LLVM_VERSION_STRING,
          [](PassBuilder &PB) {
            PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback(
                [](StringRef Name, ModulePassManager &MPM,
                   ArrayRef<PassBuilder::PipelineElement>) {
                  if (Name == "AFLCoverage") {
                    MPM.addPass(AFLCoverage());
                    return true;
                  }
                  return false;
                });
          }};
}

extern "C" LLVM_ATTRIBUTE_WEAK ::llvm::PassPluginLibraryInfo
llvmGetPassPluginInfo() {
  return getInjectFuncCallPluginInfo();
}


and type make directly. In the makefile it will do some test on the pass, but I can't see the log "IIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOOOO". I don't know where is wrong.

I am kind of sure there is something wrong with the Makefile. Is there anyway I can use only clang to import the pass instead of opt?
